# Why does .Net 6 allow me to write async methods without await?

Tags: .net, async-await, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

when i write this code

```
  public async Task CommitAsync()
        {
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

why doesn't it give an error?

Is there a use of async methods without await?

I use .Net6

Comment: CS1998 is a warning, not an error.

Comment: ok but why?  why doesn't it give an error? Is there a use without await

Comment: Nothing goes wrong at runtime, so not an error.  Have it generate a useful result with, say, `Task<int>` and now a warning is not enough anymore.  Which is probably what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In some scenerios developer may need Task/Thread instead of executed result or want to execute a task in background and no other task is dependent on that task or not. Like sending email to user after performing an action and that email result is not required, then why to make the cursor/pointer wait for the result.

This is one case study. There are many other reasons and case studies for this flaxible behaviour.

You can also read [the folowing article](https://code-maze.com/asynchronous-programming-with-async-and-await-in-asp-net-core/) for more information.